# Как добавить в ячейку datagrid combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

Заполняю динамически datagridview. Далее при двойном щелчке по опреленной ячейке в этой же ячейке надо чтоб появлялся combobox. Как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так :

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table(); //заполнение таблицы данными
        dataGridView1.CellContentDoubleClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(CreateComboboxOnDataGridView);
    }

    public void CreateComboboxOnDataGridView(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell dcombo = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            dcombo.Items.Add("A");
            dcombo.Items.Add("B");
            dcombo.Items.Add("C");
            dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex] = dcombo;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message , ex.Source);
        }
    }
```

и обязательно обработать ошибку DataError

```
    private void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
    {
      //обработка ошибки
    }
```

Comment: combobox добавляется только при клике по другой ячейке.  В чем дело?

Comment: И я сделал собвтие без content. Так как это событие не срабатывает.

Comment: 'добавляется только при клике по другой ячейке' покажите код

Comment: DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
   cell.Items.Add(hex);
   cell.Items.Add(dec);
   dt.Rows[e.RowsIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] = cell;

Comment: Используете `CellDoubleClick` событие ?

Comment: @Cергей Да. Это событие.

Comment: @VictorSayapov У меня ваш вариант работает нормально. Видимо ошибка в другом месте.

Comment: @VictorSayapov как заполняете datagrid ?

Comment: Создаю DataTable. Далее dataGridView1.Datasourse = dt. Вот  так.

Comment: @VictorSayapov `другая ячейка` это всегда одна и та же ячейка?

Comment: @Cергей Не понял вас

Comment: @VictorSayapov вы пишите `combobox добавляется только при клике по другой ячейке` т.е. вы жмете на ячейку а бокс появляется в соседней с ней?

Comment: @Cергей Я делаю двойной клик по ячейке номер 1 допустим. А после кликаю по другой ячейке, пусть будет номер 2. И вот после этого комбобокс появляется в ячейке номер 1

Comment: @VictorSayapov значит ошибка где то в другом месте. нужно посмотреть весь код. обновите вопрос, или скинте проект на dropmefiles посмотрим.

Comment: @Cергей Ошибку частично решил. Изменил свойство EditMode. Но теперь надо 3 раза кликать по комбобоксу чтобы выпадал список.